# Elements of Programming (Stepanov): how to implement Domain()

Tags: c++

Throughout the Elements of Programming, the authors use the function Domain(T) that given a function returns the type of the domain of that function.  For example:

```
template <typename Op>
    requires(BinaryOperation(Op))
Domain(Op) square(const Domain(Op)& x, Op op)
{
    return op(x, x);
}
```

Where (given Op = multiplication taking two integers) Domain(Op) returns an integer

I can't find anywhere in the book a definition for Domain().

My initial try was something along the lines of:

```
#define requires(...)
#define Domain(T) typename DomainT<T>::type

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct pair {
  pair(T1 f, T2 s) : first(f), second(s) {}
  T1 first;
  T2 second;
};

struct mult_t {
  int operator()(int a, int b) { return a * b; }
};

template <typename T>
struct DomainT {
  typedef void type;
};
// for each function in your program, specialize this struct
template <>
struct DomainT<mult_t> { typedef int type; };

template <typename Op>
requires(BinaryOperation(Op))
Domain(Op) square(const Domain(Op)& x, Op op) {
  return op(x,x);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  mult_t mult;
  std::cout << square(4, mult) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Is there a better way to implement Domain() in c++?

Comment: You might want to look at how the authors did it. [Link](http://www.elementsofprogramming.com/code.html).

Comment: In C++11, you could try to deduce the domain. [Here's a basic sketch](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3132ba8617fc3a79). It doesn't deal with constness etc yet, doesn't check whether all argument types are identical, and it suffers from the problem that you cannot deduce the full domain for overloaded `operator()` (it should be something like the union of each domain, but I think that requires reflection or manual specification; in any case, that cannot be a single parameter type for the function template to be defined in terms of the domain).

Comment: Following @jxh 's advince and `grep`, yes, basically what you show is what is done, except that it is based in a more fancy, manually defined/specializaed in most cases `template<typename F, int N> struct input_type` which "extracts" the type of the Nth argument of F . @dyp can be used for a good default of the class (absent in EOP code). http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/function_traits.html can also help. But `Domain` is a deeper concept than the argument type of a function, it is  the domain of applicability of `F`.